# Create a String-parsing method building a Map in a generic way?

Tags: java, generics

Preface: This is not an actual *problem that I have*, it just came to my mind in a "What if... ...how would I do that?" fashion.

When I have Strings consisting of several key-value pairs (like `123=456;321=654;89=90`), I can make a Map from that (`{123=456, 321=654, 89=90}`) pretty easily with a method like this:

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> makeMap(String theString) {
    String[] chunks = theString.split(";");
    Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<>(chunks.length);
    
    for (String chunk : chunks) {
        String[] chunksChunks = chunk.split("=");
        int key = Integer.parseInt(chunksChunks[0]);
        int value = Integer.parseInt(chunksChunks[1]);
        result.put(key, value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there any elegant way to "widen" this method to be a generic method, accepting e.g. all (wrappers for) primitive types?

It would be possible to write...

```
public static <K extends Object, V extends Object> Map<K, V> makeMapGeneric(String theString) {
    // ???
}
```

...but I have no idea how I would do the "castings" to the keys and values.

1. As far as I know, the primitive types do not have any common `makeXYfromString(String ...)` method, just explicit `Integer.parseInt`, `Double.parseDouble` and so on, and they do not have a common superclass/interface that I could restrict `K` and `V` to.
2. Giving the classes as argument (`makeMapGeneric(String theString, Class<K> keyClass, Class<V> valueClass)`) and writing something like `K key = keyClass.cast(keyString);`, isn't possible since you cannot *cast* a String to eg. an int, just *parse* it.

Is there any elegant solution possible?

Comment: Sidenote: `K extends Object` can just be shortened to `K`

Comment: Thank you @Lino, I didn't know that. And I think I won't shorten it there, I am a fan of "don't shorten what already is short". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide a `Function` to you method:

```java
<K, V> Map<K, V> makeMapGeneric(String theString, Function<String, K> keyFn, Function<String, V> valueFn) {

  String key = "123";
  String value = "456";

  K parsedKey = keyFn.apply(key);
  V parsedValue = valueFn.apply(key);

}
```

Now you can call it with a `Function` that converts `String` to `K` (and `V`):

```java
Map<Integer, Double> result =
    makeMapGeneric("123=456", Integer::parseInt, Double::parseDouble);
```

Comment: Ah yes, it seems that being able to handle functions like that has not really arrived at my brain yet...

Comment: @Bowi You might want to take a look at functional programming. Might open a whole new world ;)

Comment: @m0skit0 Oh yes, it does. Again and again and again and... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I took a tought on it for a few minutes and i came up with this solution

```java
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> makeMap(String input, Function<String, K> keyFunc, Function<String, V> valFunc) {
        return Arrays.stream(input.split(";"))
                .map(s -> s.split("="))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> keyFunc.apply(s[0]), s -> valFunc.apply(s[1])));
    }
```

You need to pass a two functions which will transform the string to the right value.
Use it like this:

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> x = makeMap("123=456;321=654;89=90", Integer::parseInt, Integer::parseInt);
```

Comment: Whoa! I am going to accept the answer by Benjamin M, because I can read it more easily, but I like your approach as well. :-)

Comment: Same as the previous answer but using Java streams API.